# Why does skaffold build work but not skaffold run or skaffold dev?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, skaffold

I have a local NPM/Yarn repository "verdaccio" running in a docker container, bound to my host machine at http://0.0.0.0:4873/.

I am trialling skaffold with minikube.

My Dockerfile config requires two build args:

```
ARG NPM_TOKEN
ARG PACKAGE_REPO_DOMAIN
```

Which are used in my .yarnrc.yml file:

```
yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.2.0.cjs
nodeLinker: "node-modules"
npmRegistryServer: "http://${PACKAGE_REPO_DOMAIN}:4873/"
httpRetry: 10
httpTimeout: 100000
# networkConcurrency: 2
unsafeHttpWhitelist: 
  - "0.0.0.0"
  - localhost
  - verdaccio
  - host.minikube.internal
  - host.docker.internal
npmRegistries:
  "http://${PACKAGE_REPO_DOMAIN}:4873":
    npmAlwaysAuth: true
    npmAuthToken: ${NPM_TOKEN}
```

The configured domain is `host.minikube.internal`. Below is my skaffold yaml, notice I bound network to "host":

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta28
kind: Config
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
  - image: my-app
    docker:
      dockerfile: ./my-app/Dockerfile
      target: dev
      network: "host"
      buildArgs:
        NPM_TOKEN: "***REDACTED***"
        PACKAGE_REPO_DOMAIN: "host.minikube.internal"
    context: ../
    sync: 
      manual:
        - src: 'my-app/**/*.*'
          dest: ./my-app
        - src: './shared'
          dest: './shared'
        - src: '.yarn'
          dest: '.yarn'
deploy:
  helm:
    releases:
      - name: my-app
        chartPath: ../../infrastructure/helm/charts/my-app
        artifactOverrides:
          image: my-app
        imageStrategy:
          fqn: {}
```

When running `skaffold build` then it works and builds the image fine. However when running either `skaffold dev` or `skaffold run` then `yarn install` hangs when building. This means that yarn's failing to reach the verdaccio local npm repository. I don't understand why though - surely it's still being built within the minikube environment and should use host.minikube.internal -> localhost ?

NB: I have remembered to also run this before skaffold (still fails):

```
skaffold config set --global local-cluster true
eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)
```

**Edit**

I have since made a minimum reproduction here:
https://github.com/gitn00b1337/skaffold-verdaccio

Requires yarn, minikube + helm.

CD into the project, then:

```
$ sudo chmod -R a+rw ./verdaccio/storage 
$ yarn install 
$ minikube start
$ docker-compose up (seperate terminal)
$ skaffold config set --kube-context minikube local-cluster true
$ eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)
$ skaffold build # works

$ skaffold run # fails
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On our project we had to do the following to make verdaccio work:

Add a new user:

`npm adduser --registry http://localhost:4873/`

Create an `.npmrc` file in the shared module and in the service that imports the module with the following:

```js
@my-app:registry=http://localhost:4873
strict-ssl=false
```

Publish the shared module verdaccio using `yarn build && yarn publish` and then you should be able to see it in your browser if you navigate to

`http://localhost:4873`

Then install the shared module in the service using `yarn install <shared-module>`.

I think the reason your setup is hanging is either its missing the `.nmprc` file or its needs `strict-ssl=false`

Once you add that then hopefully when you do `skaffold run` it will deploy to minikube